# viewModel inheritance not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Why doesn't my viewModel get inherited? I have the following viewModels:

```
public class BaseViewModel {

    public BaseViewModel() {
        Location = new Location { };
    }
    public Location Location { get; set; }

}

public class EditViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller:

```
        var viewModel = new EditViewModel
        {
            Book = new Book { Test = "ABC" },
            Location = { City = "AAA" }
        };
```

When I check to see what the viewModel looks like then I find it doesn't contain the location class even though my view inherits from the BaseViewModel. Can anyone see why this is. How can I ensure the view contains Location?

Comment: Is your view strongly typed to use the EditviewModel and not the BaseViewModel

Comment: Do you mean that it is `null` or that it cannot be found in `EditViewModel`?

Comment: What I am doing is checking with the debugger. I pause just after the statement that creates the viewModel. When I look there all I see is that var has a type of EditViewModel and there is the one element there for Book.

Comment: To see the Location element you need to click on the Base expanding box which is normally the first item in the list of the properties (via debugger).  This takes you into the base class properties accessible by the class instance.  In here you will see the Location property

Comment: @dreza - Thank you. I was not looking in the correct place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, because the following compiles and works just fine for me:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new EditViewModel
    {
        Book = new Book { Test = "ABC" },
        Location = new Location { City = "AAA" }
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model EditViewModel
@Model.Location.City
```

Comment: Darin - I marked you as answered because you took the time to try it out. Thanks